# Is any server that run php and servalet program?

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, servlets, xampp

is any server available that run php program and java web program in a single server and single link.
for example: xampp provide apache and tomcat for both language but separtely
like localhost link for php and servlet for localhost/8080 
i want single server single single link can run php program or servlet program whatever we want.
means localhost a link can run at php program and servlet program dont need to run diff servers separately like tomcat and apache.
if any available so give me answer please

Comment: If you want to use single server like apache or any for both then you could employee a technique reverse proxy, which will passed on servelet request to tomcat running on different port.

Comment: technique reverse proxy? can you guide me please about it

Answer (score 0):

as this could not be fit  in comment

```
<VirtualHost myhost:80>
    ServerName myhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/myapp/public
    ProxyPass / http://myapp:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://myapp:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Here http://myapp:8080 is your tomcat address mean while every one is sending request @80 and your apache is passing it to tomcat.

Comment: And it also good for security concerns, if you keep your dynamic servers in local network access.